# I need help adjusting Marzocchi dj3 2011

Tags: mountain-bike, fork, dirt-jumps

I want to increase my fork length but I don’t want to change the sag or travel or rebound.

The forks are on a Rocky Mountain frame and I want the bottom of my hard tail to be parallel with the ground and not pointing down in front.

[image: photo of fork showing desired length]

Comment: 'I want the bottom of my hard tail to be parallel' Err, why? Estimating based on some typical hardtail geometry that will raise your bars about 100-150mm, and change your head a seat tube angle by some 5-7 degrees.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus I'm impressed you can parse what that means. I'm still figuring it out.

Comment: To the OP: Those stanchions are in roooough shape. That plus the likely infeasibility of your goal makes me think you should buy a new fork.

Comment: @PaulH He's basically saying he wants to raise the headtube until there is zero bottom bracket drop.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus huh. what a strange request

Comment: @PaulH Slightly misguided, but not that strange. Many older bikes with 26" wheels have bottom brackets that are too low.  When I first got a MTB I thought i was the worst rider ever because I kept bashing the bb/chainrings on things.  And then I got a more modern 29er and that problem instantly vanished.

Comment: @AndyP I request to raise the BB I would understand. But the wording that wanting level chain stays seems odd.

The current trend in MTB is to get the BB real low. I'm not into it. At least they're finally starting to spec 170 mm cranks instead of 175s.

Answer (score 2):

I might not understand the question correctly but I don't think you can make that fork longer. The manual for the [Marzocchi Dirt Jumper 3](https://www.marzocchi.com/support/forks/2011/2011-dirt-jumper-3.aspx?idC=62354&idM=19202-1337-1608&idMy=15636&idP=18760-537&idS=15789) (click the "Tech" tab) has a lot of great information but does not indicate a way to make the fork longer.